# Easy Way to Deploy Project Created with Yeoman + Grunt + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

Huy guys,

I'm trying to deploy my AngularJS project (created using Yeoman and Grunt) to a server. Any ideas on an easy way to launch this project? We use AWS for our backend.

Comment: Are there any specific problems with deploying your application?

Answer (score 1):

Angular is just some static HTML for the most part. So just deploy it like you'd deploy any other html.

Personally, I use git for that kind of work. On my beta test server, I set up a remote repository and some post-commit hooks that let me do a `git push beta master` style deployment that rebuilds all the frontend (coffee, SASS) and backend (node) stuff.

I'm not wild about push-to-deploy for the production site, so instead I just cloned my deployment repo to that site and manually ssh to the machine, do a git pull, rebuild everything, test everything again, and then move the generated html/css/js files to the frontend directory where nginx is serving statics. I use nginx because it also serves as a reverse proxy for the node backend, otherwise I'd probably just use a plain old apache - the frontend is all static anyway.